# How to receive files on Windows SFTPd by a Unix machine

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, putty

I have a Unix tool that generates files. The same tool can run SFTP commands and push out files to other machines.

I have a Windows box that needs to accept files pushed out by the Unix machine. What do I need to install on the windows machine and how do I configure it?

Can I do it by installing just PuTTY on Windows? I tried that and used PuTTYgen to generate keys. Where is the .ssh folder in this case?

Can I do this without installing Cygwyn (preferred method is using just PuTTY)? Can Cygwyn do what I wish to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SSH/SFTP server on your Windows box. There are multiple options here. Cygwin with OpenSSH would work, but as you said, you'd prefer not to use Cygwin.

It looks like CoreFTP server support SFTP: http://www.coreftp.com/server/

CoreFTP server would probably be quickest and easiest way to get it up and running.